# Why is spring trying to URLDecode cookie value

Tags: spring-boot

If I send a request with

```
Cookie: Nonce=Tl=Q/0AUSOx[n)2z4(t]20FZv#?[Ge%H
```

Spring will fail with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid encoded sequence "%H"
    at org.springframework.util.StringUtils.uriDecode(StringUtils.java:780)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.decode(UriUtils.java:372)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeInternal(UrlPathHelper.java:522)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeRequestString(UrlPathHelper.java:513)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(ServletCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
```

Why is this happening and how can I disable url decoding of cookies?

Answer (score -1):

This is a result of this change https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11945

Here is a more update discussion https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26989#issuecomment-853177646

> For the annotation attribute, if the behavior isn't backed by the spec and if there isn't a reason to URL decode the value, then it doesn't make sense to have it, only to then have it removed in 6.0.